# How to find the summation of all elements in 2d array in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array

Let's say that I have the following 2d array:

```
let my2dArray = [[01, 02, 03, 04],
                 [05, 06, 07, 08],
                 [09, 10, 11, 12],
                 [13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

What is the easiest way to get the summation of all elements in `my2dArray`?

*Assuming that the output should be:*

*01 + 02 + 03 + 04 + 05 + 06 + 07 + 08 + 09 + 10 + 11 + 12 + 13 + 14 + 15 + 16 = **136***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to use `joined()` to flatten the array and then `reduce` to sum it:

```
let my2dArray = [[01, 02, 03, 04],
                 [05, 06, 07, 08],
                 [09, 10, 11, 12],
                 [13, 14, 15, 16]]

let result = my2dArray.joined().reduce(0, +)

print(result) // 136
```

Note that `my2dArray.joined()` doesn't create another array, but instead it creates a `FlattenBidirectionalCollection<Array<Array<Int>>>` which allows sequential access to the items, both forwards and backwards, but it does not allocate new storage.  You can of course do `Array(my2dArray.joined())` if you wish to see how it looks in array format.

Comment: Pretty nice! I didn't know that you can do this by using `joined()`, I think that I need to re-check the Instance Methods of the Array in the Swift Standard Library :)
btw, could you please tell me what `FlattenBidirectionalCollection` means? if it's a long story, could you describe it as simple as possible, or link me to a reference? Thanks alot.

Comment: Type `FlattenBidirectionalCollection` into a Playground or source file and then command-click on it. You will see the definition and properties of it.  It says that array.joined() does not allocate new storage as I figured.  It just keeps track of how to sequentially access the members of the collection.

Answer (score 3):

Just a couple more ways to do this:

```
let my2darray = [[01, 02, 03, 04],
             [05, 06, 07, 08],
             [09, 10, 11, 12],
             [13, 14, 15, 16]]



let doubleReduced = my2darray.reduce(0, {$1.reduce(0, +) + $0})
let dontForgetFlatmap = my2darray.flatMap{$0}.reduce(0,+)
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with:

**Non-Swifty Solution (Works as it should, but not "Swifty"):**

```
var summation = 0

for i in 0..<my2dArray.count {
    for j in 0..<my2dArray[i].count {
        summation += my2dArray[i][j]
    }
}

print(summation) // 136
```

**Swifty Solution (The easiest way):**

```
let summation = my2dArray.map { $0.reduce(0, +) }.reduce(0, +)

print(summation) // 136
```

***Any other -more efficient- "Swifty" solution would be really appreciated.***

Comment: Careful with the word "functional", because it has a meaning here that isn't "something that functions"